# Implementing dark theme for my HTML components

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using ExtJS to create an interface where a dark theme is being implemented.
I have managed to apply CSS styling to my main interface components (by directly modifying their css classes) and that on a button click (choice of the theme).

Now the problem is with the  dialog windows components that are created at the moment of the click on their respective menu buttons : the CSS classes are created afterhand, and so the dark theme is not applied on them too.
My question is : algorithmically speaking, to apply dark theme on these dialog windows do i have to set a global variable to check if the dark theme is enabled (variable set to `true`) in order for them to change colors ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the material design theme?  There is a built in dark/light mode.  It works very well along with changing the colors.

This does not seem to work in the fiddle. I use the code from the example kitchen sink.

extjs-7.3.1/examples/kitchensink/modern/src/controller/Main.js

onDarkModeChange is a method that will change to dark mode.
updateMaterialTheme to set the colors.

extjs-7.3.1/modern/theme-material/src/theme/Material.js - these are the built in colors.  They come from google's spec for the material design theme.

https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.0/examples/kitchensink/?modern#all  the palette button there is a switch for dark mode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am using theme-crisp , i can't find the onDarkModeChange you mentioned. Would you point it out to me ? PS : i am using ExtJS 6.2.0 i am not sure that material theme is available for that version of ExtJS

Comment: I think that is only part of the  material theme.  The material theme was added to the classic toolkit (where crisp is located) until 7.  So my post was not much help.  I am not sure how big your application is ... but the upgrade from 6 to 7 is not that big.